# asyncio websocket Send with No Prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

All `asyncio` and `websocket` documentation I have read states that packets must be sent using the `await` (or `yield from`) prefix syntax. I would like to be able to call a function to send, however, without such syntax. Is it possible to use such syntax?

#### Existing:

```
await websocket.send(message)
```

#### Desired:

```
websocket.send(message)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, asynchronous code wouldn't work without `await`/`yield from` statement. That's how asynchrony in Python organized and there [were reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218758/1113207) to do it.

You can use [synchronous websocket client](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) instead, but I don't advise you to do it: asynchronous app would work faster.

`asyncio` syntax might look uncomfortable at first sight, but when you'll practice a bit, you'll see that it only helps you.