# python3 asyncio: do all functions in a stack have to use await/async

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

When using `await/async`, does it have to go "all the way up", meaning, does every function in the call chain have to use it?

E.g.:

```
def a():
    # can't call b() here

async def b():
    return await c

async def c():
    return ...
```

I recently wondered this in the context of a flask app running under gevent, where one of the endpoints was a long running call that should be "checked upon", while not blocking other calls

```
def handler0():
    # short running
    return ...

def handler():  # blocks handler0
    return await some_long_thing()

async def some_long_thinig():
    # ..do somethiing
    return ...
```

Comment: Any synchronous call within your async functions will block the event loop - so yes, all the methods have to be async.

Comment: @rdas provided the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

> does every function in the call chain have to use it?

When you use `asyncio` module every function that `await` for something should be defined as `async` (should be a coroutine itself).

Most top level coroutine usually is main entry point of your script and executed by event loop using [asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) or similar function.

This is how `asyncio` [designed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218758/1113207): this way you always know if context can be or can't be switched in particular place.